# I need help centering a ul item within a div containing a 100% width background

Tags: css

I am new to html and css. I am currently taking a class on html5 and css3. We are required to create a website for the class. I have started creating the layout and I am having trouble getting the navigation at the top to be centered on the page. There is a Ul with a 100% background but I cannont get the buttons (text) to be centered without the Ul no longer being 100% width. `
Here is my CSS code:

```
#horizontalNav {
    display: block;
}


#horizontalNav li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 13px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}   

#horizontalNav ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #003300;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

/* Button Styles*/

```
#horizontalNav a.navBtn {
    color: #009933;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}   

#horizontalNav a.navBtn:hover {
    color: #FFFF99;
}
```

/*Drop down menu */

```
#horizontalNav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#horizontalNav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#horizontalNav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}   

#horizontalNav ul ul li a {
    color: #009933;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}   

#horizontalNav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFFF99;
}`
```

Comment: So it's the menu items that are not center not the entire menu? Please also provide some HTML.

Comment: It is working now. Someone commented and told me to use display: inline-block; rather than float: left; and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Oh ok, guess I shouldn't have deleted the comment :) I had second thoughts.

Comment: oh it was you lol. Thank you for your quick fix. I'm so new to this and honestly don't really know what I'm doing haha. Thanks.

Comment: We've all been there, just takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment stated, you cannot center floated elements. Use `display: inline-block;`

Change

```
#horizontalNav li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 13px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

to

```
#horizontalNav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 13px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. I really have no idea what I am doing haha. I was trying to figure this out for quite some time. Thanks you.